# Generate triangle wave with phase shift from square wave

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, resistance

[image]

[image]

My input is a square wave.  The output is a triangle wave. The middle of the high section the square wave should correlate with the peak of the triangle wave output. Are there are examples of circuits that can do this?

Comment: Is square wave only one stable frequency?

Comment: @Antonio51 yes,it is

Comment: I forgot, is the "center point" known?

Comment: @Antonio51 no. It is just middle of square wave which will correllate to the peak point of traingle wave

Comment: Your switch is not well wired ... The "switch" is at the right of the symbol ... At left, the command voltage ... Use also OP27 or better opamp ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is this circuit, but you need some feedback "driving" because of voltage "offsets" and "center point" not known.

Made with [microcap 12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), [new link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulml1ukc1xv1h2w/mc12cd.zip?dl=0).

[image]

The idea for finding the "center point" is this.
Integrate the square waveform.
At the end, sample the voltage of the ramp.
Take the half-point voltage.
This is the "center point" for the next cycle, for use with a comparator ... which replaced SQUARE2.

This is another updated version with "1 delay cycle" ...

[image]

Added other "waves" ...

[image]

```
* opamp integrator v013.cir Transient Analysis
* Converted From Micro Cap Source file to PSPICE
*
.FUNC DPWR(D) {I(D)*V(D)}
.FUNC BPWR(Q) {IC(Q)*VCE(Q)+IB(Q)*VBE(Q)}
.FUNC FPWR(M) {ID(M)*VDS(M)}
.FUNC HOTD(D,MAX) {IF((V(D)*I(D)>MAX),1,0)}
.FUNC HOTB(Q,MAX) {IF((VCE(Q)*IC(Q)+IB(Q)*VBE(Q)>MAX),1,0)}
.FUNC HOTF(M,MAX) {IF((VDS(M)*ID(M)>MAX),1,0)}
.PARAM LOW3MIN={IMPORT(LOW3MIN.OUT,LOW3THRES)}
.PARAM HIGH3MAX={IMPORT(HIGH3MAX.OUT,HIGH3THRES)}
.PARAM LOWLVDS={IMPORT(LOWLVDS.OUT,LOWLIMIT)}
.PARAM HILVDS={IMPORT(HILVDS.OUT,HILIMIT)}
.PARAM LIMTLVDS={IMPORT(LIMTLVDS.OUT,LVDSLIMITS)}
.FUNC SKINAC(DCRES,RESISTIVITY,RELPERM,RADIUS) {((PI*RADIUS*RADIUS)/((PI*RADIUS*RADIUS)-PI*(RADIUS-SKINDEPTHAC(RESISTIVITY,RELPERM))**2))*DCRES}
.FUNC SKINDEPTHAC(RESISTIVITY,RELPERM) {503.3*(SQRT(RESISTIVITY/(RELPERM*F)))}
.FUNC SKINTR(DCRES,RESISTIVITY,RELPERM,RADIUS,FREQ) {((PI*RADIUS*RADIUS)/((PI*RADIUS*RADIUS)-PI*(RADIUS-SKINDEPTHTR(RESISTIVITY,RELPERM,FREQ))**2))*DCRES}
.FUNC SKINDEPTHTR(RESISTIVITY,RELPERM,FREQ) {503.3*(SQRT(RESISTIVITY/(RELPERM*FREQ)))}
C1 3 Vo 1u
C2 11 Vo1 1u
C3 Vg Prst 1n
C4 0 Vo2 100u
R3 Vd 3 10k
R19 6 Vg 50
R20 3 Vo 10Meg
R21 Vg 9 10k
R22 9 Vd 10k
R23 Vg 8 10k
R24 13 11 10k
R25 11 Vo1 10Meg
R26 Prst 0 10k
R27 Vo2 Vo3 10k
R28 Vo3 0 10k
S1 8 0 Voc 0 SW1
S2 Vo1 11 Prst 0 SW2
S3 17 Vo2 Prst 0 SW3
S4 Vo 3 Start 0 SW4
V1 VC 0 DC 5 
V2 VE 0 DC -5 
V3 6 0 DC 0 PULSE (0 5 0 5e-009 5e-009 0.005 0.01)
V5 Start 0 DC 0 PULSE (0 3 0 1e-008 1e-008 0.00999999 1)
X2 0 3 VE Vo VC OP_27
X3 8 9 VE Vd VC OP_27
X4 0 11 VE Vo1 VC OP_27
X5 Vg 13 AMP PARAMS: GAIN=-1 
X6 Vo1 17 AMP PARAMS: GAIN=1 
X7 Vo3 Vo1 Voc COMP PARAMS: VOH=5 VOL=0 GAIN=1000 
*
.MODEL SW1 VSWITCH (ROFF=10MEG)
.MODEL SW2 VSWITCH (ROFF=10MEG)
.MODEL SW3 VSWITCH (ROFF=10MEG RON=0.01 VON=-4)
.MODEL SW4 VSWITCH (ROFF=10MEG)
*
*** From file D:\__Utiles\mc12cd\library\AMP.MAC
.SUBCKT AMP  PinA PinB PARAMS: GAIN=1 
E1 PINB 0 PINA 0 {GAIN}
RE1 PINA 0 1G;added by E1
.ENDS AMP
*
*** From file D:\__Utiles\mc12cd\library\COMP.MAC
.SUBCKT COMP  Inp Inm Out PARAMS: VOH=15 VOL=-15 GAIN=1000 
.PARAM VA={(VOH-VOL)/2}
.PARAM DC={(VOH+VOL)/2}
E1 Out 0 VALUE = {DC+VA*TANH(GAIN*(V(INP,INM)))}
R1 Inp 0 1e9
R2 Inm 0 1e9
.ENDS COMP
*
* OPAMP
* PINS:  1=NC+ 2=NC- 3=VEE 4=VO 5=VCC
.SUBCKT OP_27 1 2 3 4 5
IEE 10 3 8.401999999999999e-005
VS1 11 0 0
VC 5 16 1.800000000000001
VE 17 3 1.800000000000001
VLP 19 0 20
VLN 0 20 20
VS2 13 15 0
F1 13 14 POLY(5) VS1 VC VE VLP VLN 0 47746482.92756861 -47746482.92756861
+ 47746482.92756861 47746482.92756861 -47746482.92756861
E1 14 0 POLY(2) 5 0 3 0   0 0.5 0.5
H1 18 0 VS2 1000
GCM 0 12 10 0   7.557734198666343e-010
GA 12 0 6 7   0.001507964473723101
C1 6 7 8.660254037844386e-012
CE 10 14 1e-019
C2 12 13 3e-011
RC1 5 6 663.1455962162306
RC2 5 7 663.1455962162306
RE1 8 10 47.32264900962777
RE2 9 10 47.32264900962777
RE 10 14 2380385.622470841
RP 5 3 40036.65578262764
R2 12 11 100000
RO2 13 14 25
ROUTAC 15 4 50
D5 3 5 D
D3 4 16 D
D4 17 4 D
D1 18 19 D
D2 20 18 D
Q1 6 2 8 QINN
Q2 7 1 9 QINP
*
.MODEL D D ()
.MODEL QINN NPN (BF=2896.551724137931)
.MODEL QINP NPN (BF=7636.363636363636 IS=1e-016)
.ENDS OP_27
*
.OPTIONS ACCT LIST OPTS ABSTOL=1pA CHGTOL=.01pC DEFL=100u DEFW=100u DEFNRD=0
+ DEFNRS=0 DEFPD=0 DEFPS=0 DIGDRVF=2 DIGDRVZ=20K DIGERRDEFAULT=20 DIGERRLIMIT=0
+ DIGFREQ=10GHz DIGINITSTATE=0 DIGIOLVL=2 DIGMNTYMX=2 DIGMNTYSCALE=0.4 DIGOVRDRV=3
+ DIGTYMXSCALE=1.6 GMIN=1p ITL1=100 ITL2=50 ITL4=10 PIVREL=1m PIVTOL=.1p RELTOL=1m
+ TNOM=27 TRTOL=7 VNTOL=1u WIDTH=80
*
.LIB "D:\__Utiles\mc12cd\library\NOM.LIB"
*
.TEMP 27
*
.TRAN 0.00025 50m 0 10u UIC
.PLOT TRAN v([VG]) v([START]) -0.75,6.75
.PLOT TRAN v([VD]) -4,6
.PLOT TRAN v([VO]) -0.4,1.6
.PLOT TRAN v([PRST]) -5,7.5
.PLOT TRAN v([VO1]) v([VO3]) -1,4
.PLOT TRAN v([VOC]) -2,8
*
.PROBE
.END
```

Comment: Excellent answer, sir. But, why the need for V4 since its not connected to anything? Do you mind sharing the LT Spice file for that schematic? :)

Comment: V4 is controlling S1.

Comment: Hi, I have actually pasted my LT Spice circuit above in my question with the same circuit as yours. However, the output is not as expected :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't use LTspice ...  I will add a new circuit. Be aware of the functioning of switches ... Some are closed on positive voltage input command, some are open ...

Comment: @Antonio51 I believe you can put all in a folder and upload to google drive and click share. Google Drive will give you a link which then you can share here:)

Comment: @Antonio51 Perhaps you can share it to my email at codetest1312@gmail.com?

Comment: @TestingSu  Ok. Will send after.

Comment: @Antonio51 Hi sir, I am very new to LT Spice and don't know how to run the text file directly. Can just email the LT Spice schematic together in a folder to my email that is ready to run :)?

Comment: @Antonio51 Hi sir, do you mind sending it to my mail :)?

Answer (score 3):

If the frequency and the duty cycle are known then yes, it is possible, by implementing a fixed time constant for the integration, equal to half the duty cycle, and a trigger to reverse the sign when the midpoint is reached.

If the duty cycle is not known then it doesn't matter if the frequency is known, or not, it is impossible to do it, since it implies knowing beforehand when to change the sign of the integration. You would have to determine the midpoint before even knowing what the whole value of the duty cycle is.

If, OTOH, you can afford one cycle delay, then you can do it if you have a memory block: trigger at rise time, trigger at fall time, determine the duty cycle, then use that information for the next triangle.

And, if you can reverse the problem, you could generate the triangle first, and then deduce the square wave from it. That will give you what you want, but I don't know if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach this like a PLL. Let's call the square wave \$s(t)\$ and the triangular wave \$r(t)\$. The final "triangle stump wave" will be generated from that.

You know that the right shift \$\tau\$ for \$r\$ is when the integral over the absolute product of these two becomes minimal:

$$\tau_{\text{opt}} = \arg\min_\tau \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert s(t)r(t-\tau)\rvert \,\mathrm dt$$

Now, knowing that \$s(t)\$ is periodic, let's call the period \$T\$ we can put a "trigger" at the rising edge, call that time 0, and just integrate over one period. We simply stop the integration at the falling sample period:

$$\hat \tau = \arg\min_\tau \int_{t_\text{rising edge of $s$}}^{t_\text{falling edge of $s$}} \lvert s(t)r(t-\tau)\rvert \,\mathrm dt$$

So to build that is quite straightforward:
since \$s(t)\$ is only on or off, no need for a multiplier:

$$\hat \tau = \arg\min_\tau \int_{t_\text{rising edge of $s$}}^{t_\text{falling edge of $s$}} \lvert r(t-\tau)\rvert \,\mathrm dt$$

The minimum is achieved when it's 0, so we can just as well

$$\hat \tau =  \tau \text{ s.t. } \int_{t_\text{rising edge of $s$}}^{t_\text{falling edge of $s$}}  r(t-\tau) \,\mathrm dt=0$$

Great! So that means we need to build an *integrator* out of an opamp and a capacitor (thousands of example circuits available), and feed in our triangular wave. We feed that into a sample and hold circuit (thousands of circuits) triggered on the falling edge of  \$s(t)\$.

If the value is positive, you slow down your triangle wave generator oscillator. If it's negative, you speed it up.

The triangle wave can be generated in a lot of ways, but easiest here (since you need something that is a VCO) is having a harmonic, voltage-controlled oscillator, fed into a comparator to make a variable-frequency square wave, and then build an integrator to convert it to a triangular wave.

Great, now you have a synchronous triangular wave that sits "centered" on your square wave \$s(t)\$'s on periods. To convert it to your stump triangular wave, you just need a half-wave rectifier (thousands of circuits).

Comment: That's a nice solution++. A pity OP is so scarce with information.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the details still are not clear, but it looks like the entire first opamp stage in the original schematic can be replaced with a 1- or 2-gate pulse former, something with a little hysteresis.  Adjust the pulse width such that it is equal to 1/2 of the input square wave positive half-cycle, and you will get 1/4-cycle up and down ramps out of the integrator.

OR

Instead of a pulse-former, have a phase-lock loop running at twice the input frequency.  The oscillator drives the integrator stage, and now the circuit will automatically track changes in the input frequency.  The CMOS CD4046 can do this.  Auto-tracking comes at a cost - the triangle wave amplitude with vary as the input frequency changes (but the triangle peak will remain centered).

Comment: The first opamp (X3) is a switched-gain amplifier (+1 or -1).

Comment: True, but since the input is a square wave, I don't see the need for it.

Comment: It was only an explanation (for "novices"). Of course, a lot of analog circuits can be replaced by digital circuits, but not always so "simple" to understand for some ... especially without the necessary "background". :-)